# FFMPEG converts incorrect mp4 to ts

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video.MOV in h264

When I converts this video to .mp4 with -c:v copy - all is ok.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But if I converts to .ts with same -c:v copy - I receive rotated video.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.ts // output is rotaed...WTF?
```

If I specify -c:v libx264 - all is ok too.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:libx264 -c:a copy output.ts
```

Output of this command contains expected info:

```
ffmpeg ffmpeg -i video.MOV -c:v copy -c:a copy output.ts

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.MOV':
....
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 15633 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
   Metadata:
       rotate          : 90
       ...
       encoder         : H.264
   Side data:
       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
   ...

Output #0, segment, to 'output.ts':
   ...
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 15633 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 600 tbc (default)
   Metadata
       rotate          : 90
       ...
       encoder         : H.264
   Side data:
       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

I receive almost same info while converting to mp4, but here all is ok and there isn't differences in rotation while playing in player.

So what's wrong with converting to ts?
The end goal is segmentation mov file to m3u8 playlist with ts segments and here there is same problem, so I provided more simple example.

Answer (score 0):

The video was recorded in portrait/vertical mode as commonly recorded by phone users.

The phone sensor still records 1920x1080, but adds metadata instructing the player to rotate the video 90 degrees upon playback, so it plays 1080x1920 in the expected orientation.

The rotate metadata is likely not supported by the TS muxer (I did not verify).

You will probably have to re-encode. `ffmpeg` will rotate automatically when re-encoding, so that is why command #3 worked. Re-encoding is not a bad idea for M3U8 as the encoder on the phone is probably inefficient and significant file size savings may occur with not-so-much noticeable loss with libx264.